# Does stamina recovery speed stack by wearing a Chloranthy Ring and a Grass Crest Shield?

Tags: dark-souls-3

Often I wear the following items in Dark Souls 3:

**Chloranthy Ring**

> Raises stamina recovery speed.

**Grass Crest Shield**

> The grass crest is lightly imbued with magic, which slightly speeds stamina recovery.

(quotes from item description in game)

**Question**

When equipping both these items, do their effects stack?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes they do in fact stack.

Consider checking this: [Minimum and maximum stamina regens DS3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_73G3suLkko&app=desktop).

For further information on what does and does not stack in regards to stamina regen in dark souls 3 and for more info consult the wiki: [Cloranthy ring DS3 on Fextralife](https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Chloranthy+Ring). [Grass crest shield DS3 on Fextralife](https://darksouls.wiki.fextralife.com/Grass+Crest+Shield).